# Node-RED: Dynamically modify edit dialog

Tags: node-red

I am currently developing a custom node for Node-RED.

What I would like to do is the following:
In the edit dialog, I would like to initially display a single input-field and a button. When pressing the button, I want to trigger a request to my API with the value of the input field.

So far so good - that's easily manageable.

However, now I would like to dynamically modify the editor-dialog based on the response from my API, aka. display additional input fields.

Practical example: The user enters "Apple" into the input field and presses the button. My API says that an apple has the properties `weight` and `diameter`. No we should display two additional inputs for these properties in the edit dialog which can then be accessed via the config.

How is this possible with Node-RED? I've tried finding anything in the docs or in other projects but wasn't successful - hence this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the core switch and change nodes for examples.

Comment: I will have a look, thank!